# Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server] while running drop SQL DB in VSTS Powershell inline script task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In my VSTS release when I run the following inline Powershell (Version 5.1) script

```
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(".") $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "MyDB") $db.Drop()
```

I get the following error

`##[error]new-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.`

From the above error, It is clear it can not find the 'SMO Server' and I have found some solutions how to add SMO server in windows environment but don't really know who to deal with that scenario in my VSTS Powershell VSTS task? As I am a newbie in Powershell world so not even sure if the script I am running is the right approach or if there is any other way of doing the job? I will appreciate if someone can help me with the inline script option rather the script file.

Comment: The VSTS hosted agent (the one running on Windows) has [SSDT 2017 pre-installed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md#sql-server-data-tools-for-vs-2017). So, perhaps it is only a matter of loading appropriate assemblies in your script, similar to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/load-the-smo-assemblies-in-windows-powershell?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I have seen this link before but confused if i really have to load all those assemblies mentioned in that link?

Comment: Also, that is to load Assemblies in Windows Powershell. Will it be same for VSTS Powershell task? Will appreciate if you can post an answer as I am not really sure how to use that in my task.

Comment: As you can see, that article states that loading assemblies directly is usually not required. In most cases it is enough to import the SqlServer module, like this: `Import-Module SqlServer`. You should add this line to your PowerShell script (the one that is called by the VSTS PowerShell build task) before instantiating the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` object.
I'm not shaping this into an answer because I only express my assumptions at this point. If that helps, let me know and I'll shape it into the answer.

Comment: Import-Module SqlServer $srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(".") $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "MyDB") $db.Drop() I have changed my script as above and started getting the error "##[error]You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression".

Comment: Well, that's a different error - it means it was able to import the module, but failed to return the proper object of something, perhaps the database. Are you sure it exists on the build agent by the time this code is executed?

Comment: I can see the followings in the 'Path' of my agent capabilities
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\

Comment: The database called "MyDB" is not something standard. If you expect it to be there by the time your script executes, it has to be deployed to the same agent by one of the previous steps. I mean when you create an object for non-existent database and then call a method of that object - this is where the null-ref exception comes from.

Comment: "MyDB" is a dummy name and I am using the Export and Import approach as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=vsts. Export script is in my build definition and Import is in one of the release and both Export and Import are taken care by the same agent and Drop DB Powershell Agent Phase also using the same agent. Export and Import Powershell script tasks work perfectly fine. Import can only take place if Imported DB doesn't exit. In my case I do have that DB so I have to delete my existing DB before the Import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with this code: `new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(".")`, it uses windows authentication, so it uses the agent service account, make sure the agent service account can connect to the database (by default, it is Network Service if the agent is running as service)

I recommend that you can use SQL authentication and the code like this:

```
$assemblylist =   
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Instapi ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTDiagM ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.SString ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.RegSvrEnum ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Collector ",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.CollectorEnum",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DacEnum",  
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Utility",
    "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo"
foreach ($asm in $assemblylist)  
{  
    $asm = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($asm)  
}  
    $conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection("{sql server instance name}","{sql user name}","{password}")

$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conn)

Write-Host $srv.Information.Version

    $db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($srv, "{database name}") 
    $srv.KillAllProcesses($db)
    $srv.databases[$db.Name].drop()
```

Comment: I am using service agent on my target machine and I confirm it is working well for other tasks. I have followed your example but getting the error "##[error]Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\agent\_work\r1\a\SQL\Drop_SQL_Database.ps1:34 char:5
+     $srv.database[$db.Name].drop()"

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. There is a typo error. It should be $srv.databases (s) missing. Actual error is as follow      

##[error]Exception calling "Drop" with "0" argument(s): "Drop failed for Database 'TestDB'. "
At C:\agent\_work\r1\a\SQL\Drop_SQL_Database.ps1:34 char:1
+ $srv.databases[$db.Name].Drop()

Comment: I have nailed the actual error by enforcing $Error[0]|Format-List -Force to get the nested exception. "Drop with 0 argument" error is a general exception that can occur for any xyz reason but it is the nested exception that holds the actual information. In my case,  it says either DB doesn't exist or I don't have the permission. At least now I know where to look at. I have marked your answer @starian chen-MSFT.

Comment: @LearningCurve Feel free to open the new thread if you have the additional issue.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/load-the-smo-assemblies-in-windows-powershell?view=sql-server-ver16 for the source, though the answer here includes an extra assembly to load