# Set-SqlAuthenticationMode - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm attempting to change the authentication mode of an SQL instance to allow for both SQL authentication and Windows authentication through powershell. I'm using this script:

```
$username = "sqluser"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
$compName = $env:computername
Set-SqlAuthenticationMode -Credential $cred -Mode Mixed -ForceServiceRestart -ServerInstance $compName"\SQLTEST"
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error message:

```
Set-SqlAuthenticationMode : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.CloudAdapter.Data, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-SqlAuthenticationMode -Credential $cred -Mode Mixed -ForceService ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SqlAuthenticationMode], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.IaaS.SetSqlAuthenticationModeCommand
```

How do I solve this error / change the authentication mode of the server?

Comment: Do you have the SQL Server Cloud Adapter installed?

Comment: Is that a module I can install in powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research has shown that you need the SQL Server Cloud Adapter service installed to use the `Set-SQLAuthenticationMode` command. I don't know how to go about for SQL Server 2019 (version 15). So I will provide a solution to use the SMO namespace.

```
$comp = $env:ComputerName
$sql = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]::new("$comp\SQLTEST")
$sql.Settings.LoginMode = 'Mixed'
$sql.Alter()
Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLTEST' | Restart-Service -Force
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however I had to change `Restart-Service -Name 'SQL Server (SQLTEST)' -Force` to `Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLTEST' | Restart-Service `

Comment: I found I needed to [import several assemblies first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322832/2912011) before this would work.